# Tikzscale - Unscalable Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, tikzscale

I would like to use the package tikzscale to scale my picture. I use the following code

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}



%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Polygon1.tikz}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this prdouces the error "Requested to scale unscalable graphic".
My graphic is given by the following code (has to be saved as Polygon1.tikz)

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
%Polygon 21 Seiten
\node[fill=gray!10] (pol) [
  %draw,
  minimum size=0.6\textwidth,
  regular polygon, regular polygon sides=21,
  rotate=270,
  ]{};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {1/2/1,5/6/2,9/10/3} %\alpha's
  \draw[black!10!red,auto=right, ->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {3/4/1,7/8/2,11/12/3} %inverse \alpha's
   \draw[black!10!red,auto=right, -<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {2/3/1,6/7/2,10/11/3} %\beta's
  \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right, ->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {4/5/1,8/9/2,12/13/3} %inverse \beta's
   \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right, -<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {13/14/1, 16/17/2,19/20/3} %\xi's
  \draw[black!40!green,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!40!green,midway]{$\xi_ {\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {15/16/1,18/19/2,21/1/3} %inverse \xi's
   \draw[black!40!green,auto=right,-<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!40!green,midway]{$\xi_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {14/15/1,17/18/2,20/21/3} %\rho's
  \draw[violet,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[violet,midway]{$\rho_{\i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I guess that the issue is with minimum size. But I couldn't figure out how not to use it. Any ideas?
I don't want to scale the font size, this should stay the same as in the text around the picture. That's why I wanted to use tikzscale.

Comment: Why are you using `\includegraphics` to input tikz code?

Comment: @samcarter Because tikzscale works with an external file like this

Comment: @AndréC Ah yes, you are right, but then the font size is transformed too right? That's why I want to use tikzscale which in general should be able to scale everything in the picture except the font size

Comment: You want to scale some nodes (the polygon) and keep some other nodes (the labels) unscaled. There is no package that can do such a selective scale for you. You can simply add `scale=0.5` for example on the polygon node.

Comment: To answer you, you would need the complete and compileable code.

Comment: @AndréC I can compile this code... The second one has to be saved as Polygon1.tikz in the same folder as the .tex file

Comment: I can't compile code that starts with `\begin{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @AndréC That's just a tikz file and is called by the first one. If you delete [width=0.5\textwidth] the first one works without error

Comment: I have never used this feature before and I am discovering it thanks to your question which interests me more and more. If you had written the polygon with a `\foreach` on a `\draw` your request would be easy to make since you would use the native capabilities of TikZ.

Comment: I just tried to compile the first example (linewidth.tikz) of the manual and there is a compilation error. As this package dates from 2012, it was created to work with version 2.00 of TikZ, it is possible that it no longer work with version 3.01a and the latest version 3.1. You should write to him by email (in footnote 1 of his manual) to ask him exactly what he sets.

Comment: I have encountered the same errors and have seen the [project at GitHub](https://github.com/MagicMuscleMan/tikzscale). I have emailed the author as well. Is there a mechanism for unmaintained packages to be adopted by those in the know?

Answer (score 1):

I never used `tikzscale` but always could scale my pictures. You can just use `scale=0.5` and of course you may want to add `transform shape` because the whole picture is a node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 



%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
%Polygon 21 Seiten
\node[fill=gray!10] (pol) [
  %draw,
  minimum size=0.6\textwidth,
  regular polygon, regular polygon sides=21,
  rotate=270,
  ]{};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {1/2/1,5/6/2,9/10/3} %\alpha's
  \draw[black!10!red,auto=right, ->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {3/4/1,7/8/2,11/12/3} %inverse \alpha's
   \draw[black!10!red,auto=right, -<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {2/3/1,6/7/2,10/11/3} %\beta's
  \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right, ->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {4/5/1,8/9/2,12/13/3} %inverse \beta's
   \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right, -<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {13/14/1, 16/17/2,19/20/3} %\xi's
  \draw[black!40!green,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!40!green,midway]{$\xi_ {\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {15/16/1,18/19/2,21/1/3} %inverse \xi's
   \draw[black!40!green,auto=right,-<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!40!green,midway]{$\xi_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {14/15/1,17/18/2,20/21/3} %\rho's
  \draw[violet,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[violet,midway]{$\rho_{\i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want to keep the font size as it is, you can adjust the size of the polygon.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings} 



%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[->-] or \draw[->-=6pt red 1]
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ ->-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    ->-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}


%==========================  Middle & pointing arrows ==========================%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
% usage: \draw[-<-] path; or \draw[-<-=6pt red 1] path;
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\tikzset{ -<-/.style args={#1 #2 #3}{
        decoration={markings,mark= at position 0.5 with {\arrow[>=stealth]{<}}, }, 
        postaction={decorate}, }, 
    -<-/.default= {0.5 6pt black }}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Polygon 21 Seiten
\node[fill=gray!10] (pol) [
  %draw,
  minimum size=0.4\textwidth,
  regular polygon, regular polygon sides=21,
  rotate=270,
  ]{};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {1/2/1,5/6/2,9/10/3} %\alpha's
  \draw[black!10!red,auto=right, ->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {3/4/1,7/8/2,11/12/3} %inverse \alpha's
   \draw[black!10!red,auto=right, -<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!10!red,midway]{$\alpha_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {2/3/1,6/7/2,10/11/3} %\beta's
  \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right, ->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {4/5/1,8/9/2,12/13/3} %inverse \beta's
   \draw[black!10!blue,auto=right, -<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!10!blue,midway]{$\beta_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {13/14/1, 16/17/2,19/20/3} %\xi's
  \draw[black!40!green,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[black!40!green,midway]{$\xi_ {\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {15/16/1,18/19/2,21/1/3} %inverse \xi's
   \draw[black!40!green,auto=right,-<-]
     (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
     node[black!40!green,midway]{$\xi_{\i}$};
\foreach \x/\y/\i in {14/15/1,17/18/2,20/21/3} %\rho's
  \draw[violet,auto=right,->-]
    (pol.corner \x)--(pol.corner \y)
      node[violet,midway]{$\rho_{\i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this also scales the font size which I would like to avoid

Comment: @mathstackuser If you only want to make the polygon smaller, then decrease the `minimum size`, e.g. `minimum size=0.4\textwidth` and do not use scale. Or just scale the polygon node.